# handling an empty result from map in a reduce

Tags: couchdb

In couchDB, does reduce still get called if the map result is empty? if so, are both keys and value empty?

my use case (and hopefully there's a better way to do this):

I send a query to my cluster, and I require both the list of items and the count of items returned (which the map doesnt seem to provide… it only gives me the total count of the view, not the filtered viewresult). I then call reduce to get the count in a separate query.

Sometimes the ViewResult is empty, which makes reduce return null. I could look for this null, but I doubt this is the correct approach in couchdb world.

Edit: turns out the ORM I'm using does support a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The reduce function isn't called when there are no rows.

The easiest way to achieve your goal is to just do the map, and back in your code retrieve the length of the rows array that is returned from CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function being called on an empty map was actually a bug that I aided in fixing many months ago. I believe it was patched in 1.2. If you are up for using 1.1 then this bug may still exist and be useable.